# Squaring every integer in a number in the same order as number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input('num: '))
result = 0
power = -1

while x != 0:
    digit = x % 10
    digit = digit**2

    if digit > 9:
        power += 2
    else:
        power += 1
    result = result + digit * (10**power)
    x //= 10

print(result)
```

Basically, I want to square every digit in an integer. For example, 984 should be 816416 or 405 should be 16025.

The interesting thing is that if I write `result = result + digit * (10**power)` on the eighth line and make the `power = 0`, then I get the correct result. However, it sounds illogical to me because I think that we should first decide whether `digit > 9` or not. I mean, writing `result = result + digit * (10**power)` before the if statement is weird to me. So, could the code I shared work by editing some parts in this form? If not, could you explain why I should write it on the eighth line?, thanks.

Comment: I think it might be easier converting the number to a string to loop through digits

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is that you are squaring your `digit` variable before the if condition which will fail if your digit is any value less than 10. For example, for just number 4, your value of `digit` variable will be 16 and thus power will be 1 and your `result` would be 160 then.

And you need to have it at the eight line before the if statement because, the if statements determine your power variable and your value wont shift and add to the `result` variable instead. For example - for 45 you would want the output to be 1625, but if you call the statement before the if condition, the power will be 0 and thus you will get a result of 185(25+160) instead of 1625.

```
x = int(input('num: '))
result = 0
power = 0

while x != 0:
    digit = x % 10

    digit2 = digit**2
    result = result + digit2 * (10**power)

    if digit2 > 9:
        power += 2
    else:
        power += 1


    x //= 10

print(result)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can directly manipulate the nature of input number is indeed a string, which you can start working on:

```py
    >>> squares = [int(x)*int(x) for x in input('Enter a number: ')]
    Enter a number: 984
    >>> squares
    [81, 64, 16]
    >>> result = int(''.join(map(str, squares)))
    >>> result
    816416
```